Placing text next to axvline
I need to mark certain values in a plot without changing axes limits, e.g., I want a vertical line at x=pi/2 to mark the max(cos(x)) but I don't want to figure out the appropriate y limits and I just want my vertical line to go from 33% to 67% of the axes. So, as per vertical & horizontal lines in matplotlib, I am using axvline.
Now, I want to annotate the vertical line with vertical text next to it (thus annotate is out).
Thus I need to use text (see, e.g., Add text next to vertical line).
Alas, text requires x and y in data coordinates. Yes, "the coordinate system can be changed using the transform parameter", but I need x in data and y in axis coordinates!
So, how do I annotate an axvline with vertical text?
PS. Just found my question! How to set two different coordinates sytem for x and y axis in the matplotlib.pyplot.text() function?

Would it be acceptable to use transforms to convert the 33% and 67% from axes coordinates to data coordinates for ax.text?
